# Different spacing while printing to log

Tags: r, dataframe

I am printing importance matrix of xgBoost into log using write command (write works with file connection and direct it to `stderr` well). Here is the command I am using:

```
importance_matrix <- xgb.importance(names, model=bst)
write("The top 30 variables are:",stderr())
write(paste0("Feature",'\t','\t','Gain','\t','Cover','\t','Frequency'),stderr())
write(t(as.matrix(importance_matrix[1:30,])),sep="\t",ncolumns = length(names(importance_matrix)),stderr())
```

Output comes in format:

```
Feature         Gain    Cover   Frequency
pctTillDate 0.560359696 0.1314074664    0.024278250
colr_per    0.183149483 0.0962457545    0.049618673
date    0.050528297 0.1143752021    0.066395735
GREG_D  0.025648433 0.0381476142    0.018070143
LNGTD_I 0.020346020 0.0485235001    0.101322109
LATTD_I 0.019241497 0.0421892270    0.093867103
```

which make it look a bit clumsy (much clumsy in log than appearing here in SO). So in order to make it better looking I want to change last line of `t(as.matrix(importance_matrix[1:30,])),sep="\t"` such that first `sep` will be 2 tabs ('\t','\t') and rest single tab ('\t'); instead of current uniform spacing. Simple but search doesn't give any idea. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tab delimited files will look like that jagged output due to the length of content in cell, but rest assured equal amount of tabs are in between columns. Do note: text files are simply dump outputs used for data migration or archival, so presentation is not the intention.

Comment: @Parfait I do agree its not meant for presentation but in my case I am doing 400+ mapper only hadoop streaming and later on want to combine all YARN logs into one log. It is then I want to retain the readability of the important parameter. Or else 400+ logs itself are difficult to go thru, they being clumsy will just add to analyzer's agony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider padding the column names and first char column of matrix with whitespace to align each to largest character size of first column:

```
write.table(importance_matrix, sep="\t", row.names = FALSE,  quote = FALSE)
# Feature   Gain    Cover   Frequency
# pctTillDate   0.56035970  0.13140747  0.02427825
# colr_per  0.18314948  0.09624575  0.04961867
# date  0.05052830  0.11437520  0.06639573
# GREG_D    0.02564843  0.03814761  0.01807014
# LNGTD_I   0.02034602  0.04852350  0.10132211
# LATTD_I   0.01924150  0.04218923  0.09386710

new_matrix <- importance_matrix

# FIRST COLUMN LARGEST CHAR LENGTH
charmax <- max(nchar(new_matrix[,1]))

# PAD COLUMN HEADERS
colnames(new_matrix) <- lapply(1:ncol(new_matrix), function(i)
       paste0(colnames(new_matrix)[i],
              paste(rep(" ", charmax - nchar(colnames(new_matrix)[i])), collapse=""))
)

# PAD FIRST COLUMN
new_matrix[,1] <- sapply(1:nrow(new_matrix), function(i)
       paste0(new_matrix[i,1], 
              paste(rep(" ", charmax - nchar(new_matrix[i,1])), collapse=""))
)

write.table(new_matrix, sep="\t", row.names = FALSE,  quote = FALSE)
# Feature       Gain        Cover       Frequency  
# pctTillDate   0.56035970  0.13140747  0.02427825
# colr_per      0.18314948  0.09624575  0.04961867
# date          0.05052830  0.11437520  0.06639573
# GREG_D        0.02564843  0.03814761  0.01807014
# LNGTD_I       0.02034602  0.04852350  0.10132211
# LATTD_I       0.01924150  0.04218923  0.09386710
```